# why is my jump not working in python 3 / pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i get no error its just when i try to press the up arrow key it does nothing.

is there something wrong with my jump(self) in my player class? or do i need to add an update for it? im not sure

here is my code

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("use arows")


movex = 0



class player:

    def __init__(self ,x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
        self.velocity = 0
        self.falling = False
        self.onGround = False

    def jump(self):
        if(self.onGround == False):
            return

        self.velocity = 8
        self.onGround = False



    def detectCollisions(self,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):

        if (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

            return True

        elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

            return True

        else:

            return False

    def update(self, gravity, blockList):
        if (self.velocity < 0):
            self.falling = True

        collision = False
        blockX,blockY =  0,0
        for block in blockList:

            collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height )
            if collision == True:
                blockx = block.x
                blocky = block.y
                break


        if(collision == True):
            if (self.falling == True):
                self.falling == False
                self.onGround== True
                self.velocity = 0
                self.y = blocky - self.height

        if (self.onGround == False):
            self.velocity += gravity
        self.y -= self.velocity

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


class Block:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = 32
       self.height = 32

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))



gravity = -0.5

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player(0,0)

# 25 colums and 19 rows
level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range (0,len(level1)):
    for x in range (0,len(level1[y])):
        if (level1[y][x] == 1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))



gameloop = True

while gameloop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameloop = False

        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 5

            elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = -5

            elif (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                player.jump()


        if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                movex = 0

            elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                movex = 0

    screen.fill(blue)

    for block in blockList:
        block.render(screen)
    player.x += movex

    player.update(gravity, blockList)
    player.render(screen)
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Your posting contains a large amount of code not related to the problem.  Much of this is syntactically incorrect (and distracting).

Back up.  Write a few lines at a time.  Include print statements to report location and variable values.  Debug just that much.  When you have that working, add a few more lines.  As you progress, comment out print statements you no longer need.

Comment: The amount of code might be an issue (but it's hard to reduce pygame questions much, since problems arise due to the way all the different pieces fit together). I can't find anything "syntactically incorrect" though, I was able to copy paste into an editor and run the example just fine.

Comment: By the way, rather than writing something like `if (self.falling == True):`, you should just write `if self.falling:` without the comparison. This isn't the *cause* of your problem, but it probably contributed to making the cause less obvious.

Comment: +1 for providing code that I could copy and paste and run on my PC on the first try. Not sure if that's really allowed in the rules or not, but I appreciated it after some of the other questions I've answered. Plus doing 2d platformer jumping is the first game programming problem I ever worked on, about 10 years ago, and it was in Python. Nostalgia FTW. BTW, your code is way better.

Comment: it runs i just cant jump

Comment: See my answer. That's your problem. I copied your code, ran it on my computer, fixed that problem, and bam - I could jump. I'm a block, but I can jump.

Comment: ah it did can you explain to me why it fixed it? i hate to just have an answer and not know why i like to further my knowledge

Comment: I added a little more explanation. It's probably still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your update() method:

```
if(self.falling == True):
    self.falling == False
    self.onGround == True
```

These are just statements that server no purpose. You need to change them to single equals signs so that it actually changes the values of these variables. Should be:

```
if self.falling == True:
    self.falling = False
    self.onGround = True
```

By the way, parenthesis around if statement conditions are not required in Python so I removed them from my answer. I recommend you remove them too.

**Edit - Further explanation:**

var1 == var2 always returns True or False, depending on if they are equal. It does not change the values of var1 or var2.

var1 = var2 sets var1 equal to var2.

Full example:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

var1 == var2 # Nothing happens

var1 = var2  # var1 now equals 2

var3 = var1 == var2 # var3 now equals True. You might want some parenthesis around this one just for clarity.

print(var1,var2,var3) # Prints "2 2 True"
```